# jQuery DOM manipulation efficiency - building entire page with JavaScript

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm going to be starting off with a completely blank page (no elements other than html, head and body) and will then build the page using jQuery. The page contents will be in the form of JSON from an AJAX request. The contents from JSON will not have any HTML. The HTML with content will be built for different sections of the page depending on the structure of the JSON object.

This page will have various sliders, modals and other "dynamic" content.

My question is, will it be faster (lets take IE7 as the lowest common denominator) to build the HTML as one large string (using a string builder which is much faster than standard concatenation) and inject this into the body in a bulk fashion, i.e.

```
var html = "<div id='content'><p>All markup required for the page, built from the contents of the JSON object</p></div><div id='slider'>...</div>...etc."
$("body").html(html)
```

And then when that is in the DOM, use jQuery to find and apply plugins to the various dynamic parts, i.e.

```
$("#slider").sliderPlugin(options);
```

**OR**

Would it be better to create each element (or some) as a variable, then append to the body? i.e.

```
var content = $('<div/>', {id: "content"})
var slider =  $('<div/>', {id: "slider", html="<ul><li>...</li></ul>"}).appendTo(content);
$('body').append(content)
```

then with this approach I don't have to query the DOM, I only have to do this:

```
slider.sliderPlugin(options);
```

Comment: Why would you do this? If you're going to emit the markup as a string variable in javascript, why not just create it in the body?

Comment: I don't see the point in "why would you do this" questions. But, to summarize, platform restrictions, JSON content is changeable, so different JSON = different page output, the markup is not contained in JSON, just the contents of each area of the page, the markup is generated depending on the JSON strucutre. In future this allows different markup to be used for the same JSON, so the layout can be upgraded without reformating the source content.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was just curious. I would probably deliver partial HTML views through AJAX instead of JSON and construct the HTML from the model on the server.  I suppose, though, that there are instances where the data server isn't the same as the web server.  I just find that building HTML up from strings is rather tedious and error prone.  You might want to consider using http://knockoutjs.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess building the HTML once is the best way, I vaguely remember reading this somewhere

edit: I read It [here](http://jqfundamentals.com/#chapter-9) with many more jQuery optimizations.  a nice and recommended read

Answer (score 1):

The advice I've seen is that it is typically faster to supply a single large chunk of HTML to `.html()` and then rely on your browser's built-in parser to just do its thing.

However if you're going to be subsequently manipulating individual elements (e.g. adding event handlers, etc) then there's something to be said for creating those elements using the jQuery `$('<element>'`) method.

Also, given an attribute value such as `xx"xx` (nb: embedded quote marks) it's far more reliable and secure to do:

```
$('<div>', { attr: foo })
```

than to do this:

```
html += '<div attr="' + foo + '"/>';
```

Since if `foo` contains special HTML characters you'd have to escape them yourself.

Hence unless your content is *really* large I'd forget the performance concerns and go for large chunks of HTML when there's static HTML, but use the tag creation methods if you're interposing variable strings.

Answer (score 0):

The templating features of [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) seem to be a really good fit for your application.