# Which method is more performant for creating deeper nesting nodes along with the attributes using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I create deep nodes along with the attributes like this.

```
$('<div id="apple"><div id="grape"><div class="tclass1" id="orange"></div><div class="tclass2" id="watermelon"></div></div><div id="banana"><div id="papaya"></div><div id="pineaple"></div><div id="starfruit"></div></div></div>');
```

There are other more efficient ways compared to this pure methods in jQuery, as I see in [a test case](http://jsfiddle.net/6ko59joo/2/). But how about creating deep nodes like this?

I may (1) incorporate $.parseHTML() to parse the string, then append it to the parent element which is created using native javacsript document.createELement to improve the performance. Using (2) add() is possible. I can also (3) create nodes per element, and assign it attribute value using attr(), then append the child to the parent.

(1)

```
...
<!-- this is in the DOM -->
<div id="juz"></div>
...

...
var dui = document.createElement('DIV');
dui.id = 'apple';
document.getElementById("juz").appendChild(dui);
var str = '<div id="grape"><div class="tclass1" id="orange"></div><div class="tclass2" id="watermelon"></div></div><div id="banana"><div id="papaya"></div><div id="pineaple"></div><div id="starfruit"></div></div>';
var html = $.parseHTML(str);
$("#juz").append(html);
...
```

(3)

```
...
<!-- in the dom -->
<div id="juz"></div>
...

...
var smj = $("<div>").attr("id","apple");
var sem = $("<div>").attr({"class":"tclass1","id":"orange"});
var rts = $("<div>").attr({"class":"tclass2","id":"watermelon"});
var rrw = $("<div>").attr("id","grape");
var jhy = $("<div>").attr("id","papaya");
var hsy = $("<div>").attr("id","pineaple");
var poi = $("<div>").attr("id","starfruit");
var las = $("<div>").attr("id","banana");
var gty = las.append(jhy).append(hsy).append(poi);
var pwq = rrw.append(sem).append(rts);
var pytr = smj.append(pwq).append(gty);
$("#juz").append(pytr);
...
```

However, I doubt which one is the fastest for such deeper nesting nodes, as I can't make a reliable test case. Do you have any idea on which method should I prefer over the others, and would you provide the test case? Thanks!

Comment: Questions about code should include the code you're asking about in the actual question (not only in an external reference).

Comment: any answers are likely only guesses, use jsperf.com to test it yourself

Comment: What are _"deep nodes"_ ? Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net demonstrate different options described ? Tried `document.createDocumentFragment()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment  _"Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow (computation of element's position and geometry). Consequently, using document fragments often results in better performance."_ ?

Comment: @guest271314 Deep nodes, just like the example above highlighted inside <pre><code>, I mean just deep html elements.

Comment: "nesting" elements http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists#Nesting_lists ?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated the code just like what is in my mind. Sorry for not updating the second method. The second will be like $("string").add("string").add("string"). ... .add("string");, then appending; What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

As with all performance related issues:

1. Premature performance optimization is evil.  It just causes you to spend time trying to improve performance before you even know that it's worth any effort to work on performance in that area.
2. Without strong evidence that you have a performance issue to worry about, code should be written in the clearest, simplest, easiest to maintain way possible.
3. If you need to work on performance issues, performance problems and solutions can only be addressed through direct measurement of both the current code and theorized solutions.  And, measurement has to be done in the relevant target environments with representative data.

In the case you illustrate of a series of HTML elements, the simplest way to write that code is to use a string of HTML and set that as the `.innerHTML` of a container.  That can be done with two lines of code and it's completely obvious (e.g. easy to understand) what the code is doing.  For large blocks of HTML, one might even read a template from another file.  Or, if the content is to be added to an existing container, an HTML fragment can be used.

So, I'd suggest you start with the simplest approach and only deviate from that when you have a tested, measured and quantified reason for doing so:

```
var html = '<div id="apple"><div id="grape"><div class="tclass1" id="orange"></div><div class="tclass2" id="watermelon"></div></div><div id="banana"><div id="papaya"></div><div id="pineaple"></div><div id="starfruit"></div></div></div>'
$("#juz").append(html);
```

Note, the jQuery method `.append()` accepts an HTML string directly, there is no need to parse the HTML yourself beforehand.

---

Here are some general notes about performance of DOM manipulations:

1. Lots of consecutive DOM manipulations is often the slowest way of doing things.  Each one triggers relayout and repaint, each one triggers DOM tree updates, etc...
2. One large manipulation by setting the `.innerHTML` property from a string of HTML can be surprisingly fast (though will vary by browser).  But, do not do `x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML + newHTML` because that reparses existing HTML, and replaces existing DOM elements with entirely new DOM elements.
3. If you have to do a lot of DOM insertions in code, then it is generally best to build up a tree of DOM nodes outside the DOM and then insert that into the DOM in one final operation.  You can use either a common parent or a DOM fragment to parent the nodes you are creating.  This means that the majority of DOM changes will be done to the external tree before it is actually in the live DOM that is being displayed.

---

Related answers:

[jQuery DOM manipulation efficiency - building entire page with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259150/jquery-dom-manipulation-efficiency-building-entire-page-with-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have also read somewhere else that premature optimization is evil. But someone tells me that too much strings is not good.

Comment: @MattSadewa - remember, the browser has fully optimized native code for parsing large strings of HTML and turning them into DOM nodes because that's what it does every time you load a page.  Whereas, a bunch of Javascript making one at a time changes to the DOM is not that at all.  If you really want to know, come up with a representative set of HTML and write a performance test.  All performance questions must be answered with testing.  But, I suspect the more important factor here is which makes easier to write and more robust code.

Comment: I see. I just tested them at Jsfiddle. What you suggested performs fastest. Do you have any suggestion to make a reliable performance test, like the parameters, assessment, etc?